# Pandas efficiency with multiple boolean masking

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a data with 600 rows and 8 columns, where I need to perform complex maskings to correctly obtain some key-value pairs. To this end, I do the following operations...

1) Load data from csv into an original dataframe
2) perform some calculations to create 4 more columns (12 columns in total now)
3) perform boolean maskings to section the original dataframe into SEVERAL smaller dataframes
4) finally loop through these smaller dataframes(for loops - within 10-15 rows dataframe) as key-value pairs

This has left my code bloated and running at ~ 8.9secs.(Not good)

I am talking about roughly more than 100 maskings. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240803/pandas-dataframe-search-is-linear-time-or-constant-time), I believe, this is not the most efficient way.

Should I just get rid of all the maskings and start over to find a faster way?

NOTE: If this is not the right channel of stackoverflow to ask this question,, please flag me and point me to the right one. TIA.

Comment: I think it is very general question, hard to answer. Can you add your code, sample data and desired output?

Comment: Your complex criteria should be simplify for sample data.