# What's the computational complexity of .iloc[] in pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, indexing, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand what's the execution complexity of the `iloc` function in pandas.
I read the following Stack Exchange thread ([Pandas DataFrame search is linear time or constant time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240803/pandas-dataframe-search-is-linear-time-or-constant-time)) that:

> *"accessing single row by index (index is sorted and unique) should have runtime O(m) where `m << n_rows`"*

mentioning that `iloc` runs on `O(m)` time. What is `m` (linear, log, constant,...)?

Some experiments I ran:

```
import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,4,5]], columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> a = a.set_index('a').sort_index()
>>> a
  b c
a
1 3 4
1 4 5
2 2 3
2 3 4

>>> a.iloc[[0,1,2,3]]
  b c
a
1 3 4
1 4 5
2 2 3
2 3 4
```

So `iloc` clearly works with offsets and not on the integer-based index (column `a`). Even if we delete few rows at the top, the `iloc` offset-based lookup works correctly:

```
>>> a.drop([1]).iloc[[0,1]]
  b c
a
2 2 3
2 3 4
```

So why isn't `iloc` offset-lookup running on a comparable time to numpy arrays when each column is simply a numpy array that can be accessed in constant time (few operations)? And what's its complexity?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to compare the efficiency of pandas vs numpy on a 10000000x2 matrix. Comparing the efficiency of a value increment per row in a DataFrame `df` and an array `arr`, with and without a `for` loop:

```
# Initialization
SIZE = 10000000
arr = np.ones((SIZE,2), dtype=np.uint32)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

# numpy, no for-loop
arr[range(SIZE),1] += 1

# pandas, no for-loop
df.iloc[range(SIZE),1] += 1

# numpy, for-loop
for i in range(SIZE):
  arr[i,1] += 1

# pandas, for-loop
for i in range(SIZE):
  df.iloc[i,1] += 1
```

| Method | Execution time |
| --- | --- |
| numpy, no for-loop | 7 seconds |
| pandas, no for-loop | 24 seconds |
| numpy, with for-loop | 27 seconds |
| pandas, with for-loop | > 2 hours |

Comment: When benchmarknig performance, always state both your python, pandas and numpy versions. Also you're using np.uint32 datatype with a 64b build, that'll be slower.

Comment: Your pandas for-loop timing is obviously anomalous, guessing every single `.iloc[]` call forced it to make a copy. See [In Pandas, does .iloc method give a copy or view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972633/in-pandas-does-iloc-method-give-a-copy-or-view), and tell us if your memory usage blew out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There likely isn't one answer for the runtime complexity of `iloc`. The method accepts a huge range of input types, and that flexibility necessarily comes with costs. These costs are likely to include both large constant factors and non-constant costs that are almost certainly dependent on the way in which it is used.

One way to *sort of* answer your question is to step through the code in the two cases.

#### Indexing with `range`

First, indexing with `range(SIZE)`. Assuming `df` is defined as you did, you can run:

```py
import pdb
pdb.run('df.iloc[range(SIZE), 1]')
```

and then `s`tep through the code to follow the path. Ultimately, this arrives at [this line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/71dfed7455106f79869641c44f0ab94258616ce2/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L717):

```py
self._values.take(indices)
```

where `indices` is an ndarray of integers constructed from the original `range`, and `self._values` is the source ndarray of the data frame.

There are two things to note about this. First, the range is materialized into an ndarray, which means you have a memory allocation of at least `SIZE` elements. So...that's going to cost you some time :). I don't know how the indexing happens in NumPy itself, but given the time measurements you've produced, it's possible that there is no (or a much smaller) allocation happening.

The second thing to note is that `numpy.take` makes a copy. You can verify this by looking at the `.flags` attribute of the object returned from calling this method, which indicates that it owns its data and is not a view onto the original. (Also note that `np.may_share_memory` returns `False`.) So...there's *another* allocation there :).

*Take home:* It's not obvious that there's any non-linear runtime here, but there are clearly large constant factors. Multiple allocations are probably the big killer, but the complex branching logic in the call tree under the `.iloc` property surely doesn't help.

#### Indexing in a loop

The code taken in this path is much shorter. It pretty quickly arrives [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/71dfed7455106f79869641c44f0ab94258616ce2/pandas/core/indexing.py#L880):

```py
return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
```

The really crappy runtime here is probably due to that tuple-unpacking. That *repeatedly* unpacks and repacks `key` as a tuple on *each* loop iteration. (Note that `key` is already the tuple `(i, 1)`, so that sucks. The cost of accepting a generic iterable.)

#### Runtime analysis

In any case, we can get an estimate of the actual runtime of your particular use case by profiling. The following script will generate a log-spaced list of array sizes from 10 to 10e9, index with a range, and print out the time it takes to run the `__getitem__` method. (There are only two such calls in the tree, so it's easy to see which is the one we care about.)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import cProfile
import pstats

sizes = [10 ** i for i in range(1, 9)]
for size in sizes:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((size, 2)))
    with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
        pr.enable()
        df.iloc[range(size), 1]
        pr.disable()
        stats = pstats.Stats(pr)
        print(size)
        stats.print_stats("__getitem__")
```

Once the output gets above the minimum resolution, you can see pretty clear linear behavior here:

```
Size     | Runtime
------------------
10000    | 0.002
100000   | 0.021
1000000  | 0.206
10000000 | 2.145
100000000| 24.843
```

So I'm not sure what sources you're referring to that talk about nonlinear runtime of indexing. They could be out of date, or considering a different code path than the one using `range`.

Comment: bnaecker that answered my question. I had read the following source
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240803/pandas-dataframe-search-is-linear-time-or-constant-time
that mentions
"accessing single row by index (index is sorted and unique) should have runtime O(m) where m << n_rows"
without telling the order of `m`. 

I should have done the profiling myself, and I'd verify that m is indeed a constant and the lookup runs in constant complexity (big O notation) however with a large constant value compared to numpy array.
Kudos and thank you for the explanation of loop vs range access!

Comment: @BrunoMaga That linked question is interesting. The accepted answer is unsatisfying, however. As you pointed out, they quote a runtime of `O(m)`, without stating anything about `m`. And they don't actually do an analysis! The answer shows runtime of different methods for a _single_ sized input, not how the methods vary as a function of input size. Regardless, I'm glad you found the answer helpful. Please mark it as accepted if you find it... acceptable :)